# How do I prevent `format()` from inserting newlines in my string?

Tags: python, string-formatting

It might be my mistake, but `cmd = 'program {} {}'.format(arg1, arg2)` will always get a newline between the two args... like this
`program 1\n2`

what should i do to put them in one line (`cmd` need to be passed to system shell)?

Comment: There shouldn't be new line, only if you have `arg1='some-string\n'`

Comment: actually it doesnt, make sure you dont have `\n` at the end of `arg1`

Comment: `str.format()` only inserts what you pass into the method to be inserted. If that value contains a newline, simply pass in the value without the newline instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arg1` contains `\n`. Use [strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

```
cmd = 'program {} {}'.format(arg1.strip(), arg2.strip())
```

Comment: thanks for the reminder... the `arg` was read from a text file so it contains a newline... my mistake..